# Open source RTP mixer/translator exe or sdk

Tags: c++, open-source, audio, rtp

Hi I need opens source (win 32) sdk or free server with signaling protocol, which implements RTP translator or mixer. e.g receives RTP traffic from one connection and transmits it on the other. Does not have to have conferencing capabilities.

Server should implement some kind of protocol which opens, bridges, and closes connections.

Ready made server is much preferable than just common RTP SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found nothing real.

RtpProxy approaches the goal but I wasn't able to use it because it is for linux only.

I tweaked Rtp Relay test program included in Live555

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg - ffserver

Comment: You mean by tweaking the code I can replace file-to-rtp functionality with rtp-to-rtp?

Answer (score 0):

look at VLC

look at the command line option of VLC